# View not getting updated after component variable is changed in Angular2

Tags: javascript, angularjs, node.js, angular

View {{user.email}} not getting updated after the component variable 'user' in SidebarComponent is updated. It works after manual page refresh. 
I have split the material design into separate components. The side bar component is as follows

SidebarComponent.ts

```
import {Component} from 'angular2/core';
import {Router, RouteConfig, ROUTER_DIRECTIVES,CanActivate} from 'angular2/router';
import {HomeComponent} from '../home/HomeComponent'
import {DashboardComponent} from './DashboardComponent'

@Component({
    selector: 'app-sidebar',
    template: `
      <header class="demo-drawer-header">
          <img src="../app/assets/images/user.jpg" class="demo-avatar">
          <div class="demo-avatar-dropdown">
            <span>{{user.email}}</span>
            <div class="mdl-layout-spacer"></div>
            <button id="accbtn" class="mdl-button mdl-js-button mdl-js-ripple-effect mdl-button--icon">
              <i class="material-icons" role="presentation">arrow_drop_down</i>
              <span class="visuallyhidden">Accounts</span>
            </button>
            <ul class="mdl-menu mdl-menu--bottom-right mdl-js-menu mdl-js-ripple-effect" for="accbtn">
              <li class="mdl-menu__item">hello@example.com</li>
              <li class="mdl-menu__item">info@example.com</li>
              <li class="mdl-menu__item"><i class="material-icons">add</i>Add another account...</li>
            </ul>
          </div>
        </header>
        <nav class="demo-navigation mdl-navigation mdl-color--blue-grey-800">

          <a class="mdl-navigation__link" [routerLink]="['./Dashboard']"><i class="mdl-color-text--blue- grey-400    material-icons" role="presentation">dashboard</i>Dashboard</a>


          <a class="mdl-navigation__link" [routerLink]="['./Home']"><i class="mdl-color-text--blue-grey-400     material-icons" role="presentation">assignment</i>Tasks</a>

          <a class="mdl-navigation__link" href=""><i class="mdl-color-text--blue-grey-400 material-icons"     role="presentation">delete</i>Trash</a>
        </nav>
    `, 

    directives: [ROUTER_DIRECTIVES,DashboardComponent]
})

export class SidebarComponent { 

  user = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('profile'));  

  constructor() {}
```

}

I have a custom router-outlet to check user authentication which is as follows

```
import {Directive, DynamicComponentLoader, ElementRef} from "angular2/core";
import {AuthService} from '../../services/AuthService'
import {Router, RouterOutlet, ComponentInstruction} from "angular2/router";

@Directive({
    selector: 'auth-router-outlet'
})
export class AuthRouterOutlet extends RouterOutlet {
    private _protectedRoutes = {
        'app/**': true,
        'app/home': true,
        'app/dashboard': true,
        'app/about': true
    };

    constructor(_elementRef: ElementRef, _loader: DynamicComponentLoader, private _router: Router, nameAttr:     string, private _authService: AuthService) {
        super(_elementRef, _loader, _router, nameAttr);
    }

    activate(nextInstruction: ComponentInstruction): Promise<any> {
        if (this._protectedRoutes[nextInstruction.urlPath]) {        
            if (!this._authService.loggedIn()) {
                this._router.navigate(['Login']);
            }
        }

        return super.activate(nextInstruction);
    }
}
```

The aboue outlet uses the following Authservice.ts which sets the Profile object in Localstorage

```
import {Injectable} from 'angular2/core';
import {ROUTER_DIRECTIVES, Router} from "angular2/router";
import {tokenNotExpired} from 'angular2-jwt';


declare var Auth0Lock: any;

@Injectable()
export class AuthService {

constructor(private router: Router) {}

  private useremail;

  lock = new Auth0Lock('KEY','URL');

  login() {
   this.lock.show((error: string, profile: Object, id_token: string) => {
     if (error) {
       console.log(error);
       return false;
     }

     localStorage.setItem('profile', JSON.stringify(profile));
     localStorage.setItem('id_token', id_token);

     /*var profiletemp = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('profile'));
     this.setUserEmail(profiletemp.email);*/

     this.router.navigate(['Dashboard']);

    });
 }

 logout() {
   localStorage.removeItem('profile');
   localStorage.removeItem('id_token');
 }

 loggedIn() {
    return tokenNotExpired();
  }

/* setUserEmail(val) {         -- not required as profile object is in localstorage
        this.useremail = val;
  } 

 getUserEmail() {
        return this.useremail;
  } */ 
}
```

index.html

```
<html>
  <head>
    <title>MEAN</title>
    <base href="/"/>

    <!-- 1. Load libraries -->
    <script src="libs/angular2/bundles/angular2-polyfills.js"></script>
    <script src="libs/systemjs/dist/system.src.js"></script>


    <script src="libs/rxjs/bundles/Rx.js"></script>
    <script src="libs/angular2/bundles/angular2.dev.js"></script>
    <script src="libs/angular2/bundles/router.dev.js"></script>
    <script src="//cdn.auth0.com/js/lock-9.0.min.js"></script>
    <script src="libs/angular2/bundles/http.dev.js"></script>
    <script src="https://code.getmdl.io/1.1.3/material.min.js"></script>

    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no"></    meta>

    <meta name="mobile-web-app-capable" content="yes">
    <link rel="icon" sizes="192x192" href="app/assets/images/android-desktop.png"></meta>

     <!-- Add to homescreen for Safari on iOS -->
    <meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-capable" content="yes"></meta>
    <meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-status-bar-style" content="black"></meta>
    <meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-title" content="Material Design Lite"></meta>
    <link rel="apple-touch-icon-precomposed" href="app/assets/images/ios-desktop.png">

    <!-- Tile icon for Win8 (144x144 + tile color) -->
    <meta name="msapplication-TileImage" content="app/assets/images/touch/ms-touch-icon-144x144-precomposed.png"><    /meta>
    <meta name="msapplication-TileColor" content="#3372DF"></meta>

    <link rel="shortcut icon" href="app/assets/images/favicon.png">


   <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:regular,bold,italic,thin,light,    bolditalic,black,medium&amp;lang=en">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://code.getmdl.io/1.1.3/material.cyan-light_blue.min.css"> 
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="app/assets/styles.css">
    <style>
    #view-source {
      position: fixed;
      display: block;
      right: 0;
      bottom: 0;
      margin-right: 40px;
      margin-bottom: 40px;
      z-index: 900;
    }
    </style>

    <!-- 2. Configure SystemJS -->
    <script>
      System.config({
        packages: {        
          app: {
            format: 'register',
            defaultExtension: 'js'
          } 
        } ,
        map: {
          "angular2-jwt": "libs/angular2-jwt/angular2-jwt.js"
        }
      });
      System.import('app/bootstrap')
            .then(null, console.error.bind(console));
    </script>

  </head>
  <!-- 3. Display the application..All ExpressJS requests come to this index file and from here Angular routing     takes over-->
  <body>
    <my-app>Loading the application...</my-app>
  </body>

</html>
```

I have the angular2-polyfills.js included in the index. The SidebarComponent view does not update after the corresponding variable in the component is changed.

Any ideas ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think that you need to notify the `SidebarComponent` component that the `profile` was updated within the local storage with the `AuthService` shared service. Be sure that this service is configured when bootstrapping your application.

```
constructor(private router: Router) {}
  private useremail;
  profileUpdated$:Suject<any> = new Subject(); // <-------

  lock = new Auth0Lock('KEY','URL');

  login() {
    this.lock.show((error: string, profile: Object, id_token: string) => {
      if (error) {
        console.log(error);
        return false;
      }

      localStorage.setItem('profile', JSON.stringify(profile));
      localStorage.setItem('id_token', id_token);
      this.profileUpdated$.next(profile); // <-------

      this.router.navigate(['Dashboard']);
    });
}

logout() {
  localStorage.removeItem('profile');
  localStorage.removeItem('id_token');
  this.profileUpdated$.next(null); // <-------
}
```

Within the `SidebarComponent` component you can subscribe on profileUpdated$ to be notified and update the corresponding template:

```
@Component({
  (...)
})
export class SidebarComponent { 

  user = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('profile'));  

  constructor(private service:AuthService) {
    this.profileUpdated$.subscribe(profile => { // <-----
      this.user = profile;
    });
  }
```

Comment: Still the same behavior. I have to refresh the page manually to reload the sidebar.

Comment: Does the callback is called within the `SidebarComponent` component? Is the `AuthService` service only defined when bootstrapping the application (and not in `providers` attribute of components)?

Comment: i don't quite understand about the callback in SidebarComponent?? AuthService is only in the bootstrap and not in the providers of any component.

Comment: I made the following change to the sidebar constructor 
  **constructor(private service:AuthService) {
  this.user = this.service.profileUpdated$.subscribe(profile => { 
      this.user = profile;
  });
  }**      Now I don't have to refresh the page, but some clicks. still not perfect, but a step closer.

Comment: Great! I think that you need to set the `user` with the subscription: `this.user = this.service...`.

Comment: How can i do that ? this concept is fairly new to me.

Comment: In fact, the `subscribe` method returns a subscription and not the result... The result will be received as parameter of the callback you provided when calling this `subscribe` method.

Comment: Look at this line https://github.com/auth0/auth0-angular2/blob/master/webpack/src/app/auth/auth.service.ts#L36 It is from auth0 tutorial https://auth0.com/docs/client-platforms/angular2

Comment: perfect :) .. Cheers. Thanks a lot.  Please edit the answer a bit, in case somebody needs it.

Answer (score 0):

What is your `localStorage.getItem('profile')` return.

```
user = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('profile'));
```

You should create a user model first and then assign `json result` on this model. Something like this

**User.ts**

```
export class User {
   email:string;
}
```

**Change SidebarComponent.ts class**

```
export class SidebarComponent { 
  user:User ; 
  constructor() {
     this.user=JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('profile'));  
  }
}
```

Comment: Even if i do that, the sidebar constructor is not called after I login. So the Sidebar is already loaded before I login.  That is why when I refresh the page, it all works fine.